# Terraform Azurerm azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm “Set number of instant recovery snapshot(s)”

Tags: azure, backup, terraform, snapshot, recovery

I have successfully created daily and weekly backup policies using Terraform and both work fine. The Azure Portal however shows a red mark under "Instant Restore" on the policy blade saying "Retain instant recovery snapshot(s) for" and the value appears as 2 days. I need to change this value to 5; however, I don't see an option to alter it in Terraform. I was wondering if I should use "azurerm_snapshot" resource type to change it or if there is a workaround available in TF for it.

```
resource "azurerm_recovery_services_protection_policy_vm" "backup_policy_weekly" {
  name                = "${var.RG4VM}-weekly-bkp-policy"
  resource_group_name = "${var.RG4VM}"
  recovery_vault_name = "${azurerm_recovery_services_vault.backup_vault.name}"
  depends_on          = ["azurerm_recovery_services_vault.backup_vault"]
   timezone            = "UTC"

  backup {
    frequency = "Weekly"
    time      = "18:30"
    weekdays  = ["Friday"]
  }

  retention_weekly {
    count    = "2"
    weekdays = ["Friday"]
  }

  retention_monthly {
    count    = "1"
    weekdays = ["Friday"]
    weeks    = ["Last"]
  }
}
```

Expected: Snapshot set to 5, as it is the minimum value
Actual: 2

Thank you/Asghar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue, I just can say the property is not supported by Terraform. You can see it in the [Azure REST API for Recovery Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/backup/protectionpolicies/createorupdate#azureiaasvmprotectionpolicy) as property `instantRpRetentionRangeInDays` and use the request body like this:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "backupManagementType": "AzureIaasVM",
    "schedulePolicy": {
      "schedulePolicyType": "SimpleSchedulePolicy",
      "scheduleRunFrequency": "Weekly",
      "scheduleRunDays": [
        "Friday"
      ],
      "scheduleRunTimes": [
        "2018-07-30T18:30:00Z"
      ],
      "scheduleWeeklyFrequency": 0
    },
    "retentionPolicy": {
      "retentionPolicyType": "LongTermRetentionPolicy",
      "weeklySchedule": {
        "daysOfTheWeek": [
          "Friday"
        ],
        "retentionTimes": [
          "2018-07-30T18:30:00Z"
        ],
        "retentionDuration": {
          "count": 5,
          "durationType": "Weeks"
        }
      }
    },
    "instantRpRetentionRangeInDays": 5,
    "timeZone": "UTC",
    "protectedItemsCount": 0
  }
}
```

Or you also can use the [Azure Template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-recovery-services-weekly-backup-policy-create/azuredeploy.json#L113) and it also shows in it. But you cannot find the property in the Terraform. So I suggest you can use the Azure REST API or Template to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks Charles. Appreciate your quick response.